# Converting a JSONArray to String and then back to JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

I am trying to convert a string to jsonarray

I want to store string in MYsql

Code -

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.*"%>

<%
try 
{
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
jArray.add("test");
String s = jArray.toString();
JSONArray newJArray = new JSONArray(s);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace(response.getWriter());  
} 
%>
```

But it gives error
The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined

I want to get jsonarray string back as a JSONArray for further use.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes-consider looking at the actual api docs and usage notes.

Comment: I do not know much, but fromObject may be a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();
config.setIgnoreDefaultExcludes(false);
config.setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT);  
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString,config); 
List list=JSONArray.toList(jsonArray,beanClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

The import you are using is:

```
 <%@page import="net.sf.json.*"%>
```

instead you should use:

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
```

You can download the jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

Then use the code :

```
    <%
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    jArray.put("test");
    String s = jArray.toString();
    JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(s);
    %>
```